# Newbie: How to implement a simple counter in a window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm trying to implement a very simple program in Python3/Tk : a simple windows with one text sentence "You have clicked *i* times." and a button. When ones clicks on the button, the sentence updates the value of *i* to the next integer.
 Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import *
# Définition du compteur d'affichage
i=0
def f():
    global i
    i=i+1
# Corps du programme
def affichage():
    monTexte.set("Le nombre de clicks est "+str(i)+".")
# Affichage du texte 1
fen=Tk()
monTexte=StringVar()
monTexte.set("Le nombre de clicks est "+str(i)+".")
texteLabel = Label(fen, textvariable = monTexte)
texteLabel.pack()
# Affichage du bouton 1
btn=Button(fen, f(), text="+1", command=affichage)
btn.pack()
fen.mainloop()
```

I do understand that you have to execute the function *f()* every time one clicks on the button but the way I've implemented it executes the function only once. Maybe there's some kind of loop to implement but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance,

Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the command that your button executes to the command that increments your i value eg:

`btn=Button(fen, text="+1", command=f)`

Where your function 'f' is:

```
def f():
    global i
    i=i+1
    monTexte.set("Le nombre de clicks est "+str(i)+".")
```

### Program:

```
from tkinter import *

i=0
def f():
    global i
    i=i+1
    monTexte.set("Le nombre de clicks est "+str(i)+".")

fen=Tk()

monTexte=StringVar()
monTexte.set("Le nombre de clicks est "+str(i)+".")

texteLabel = Label(fen, textvariable = monTexte)
texteLabel.pack()

btn=Button(fen, text="+1", command=f)
btn.pack()

fen.mainloop()
```